# How to validate ajax form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery FormBuilder Plugin](https://github.com/botskonet/jquery.formbuilder) to generate a form builder in my app.

The problem is I have another two input field that needs to be submitted along with this.

My form structure is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#my-form-builder').formbuilder({
            'save_url' : 'examplesave',
            'load_url' : 'examplejson',
            'useJson' : true
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="fname" />
    <input type="text" id="lname" />
    <div id="my-form-builder"></div>
</form>
```

I've edited the `jquery.formbuilder.js` file to append the other two input fields:

```
// saves the serialized data to the server
            var save = function () {
                    var fname= $('#fname').val();
                    var lname= $('#lname').val();

                    if (opts.save_url) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: opts.save_url,
                            data: $(ul_obj).serializeFormList({
                                prepend: opts.serialize_prefix
                            }) + "&form_id=" + form_db_id + "&fname=" +fname + "&lname=" +lname,
                            success: function () {}
                        });
                    }
                };
```

So far, so good. This works perfectly fine.
The problem is I want to use `jquery Validate plugin` to validate the input fields before submitting.
Now I can use `jQuery Form plugin` on `(document).ready` to validate the fields. Something like:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "examplesave",
                    data: ?????????????????????????????????
                    beforeSubmit : function() {
                        $("#myForm").validate({
                            rules : {
                                fname : {
                                    required : true
                                },
                                lname : {
                                    required : true
                                }
                            },
                            messages : {
                                fname : "Please enter...",
                                lname : "Please enter..."
                            }
                        });
                        return $("#myForm").valid();
                    },
                    success : function() {}
                });
```

But how do I get the data

```
data: $(ul_obj).serializeFormList({
                                    prepend: opts.serialize_prefix
                                }) + "&form_id=" + form_db_id + "&fname=" +fname + "&lname=" +lname
```

part? It just submits the form as it is & the jQuery formbuilder doesn't get to serialize the inputs together. How can I use the serialize plugin here?
I'm really stuck bad. I'm not very good at javascript.

Can someone please guide me. I can add more details if this is not clear. I'm racking by brains apart. Is there another approach to it too? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

try using serialize() function

```
  ...
  data:$("#myForm").serialize();
```

this serialize all you from elements

Comment: Well, I guess you got me wrong. I want a way to get data: $(ul_obj).serializeFormList({
                                prepend: opts.serialize_prefix
                            }) + "&form_id=" + form_db_id + "&fname=" +fname + "&lname=" +lname, in the data part. There is a plugin function to serialize it in it's own way. How to get that part?